# Showing that $||w-u||=||w-v||.$ in a circle with perpendicular tangents

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, normed-spaces, circles, tangent-line

**[See diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuZaT.jpg)**

Points $A$ and $C$ with position vectors $u$ and $v$ lie on the circle with centre $0$ and radius $r$. Tangents to the circle at $A$ and $C$ meet at the point $B$ with position vector $w$.

Show that $||w-u||=||w-v||.$

I have attempted this algebracilly reaching:
$\sqrt{<w,w>-2r^2+<u,u>}=\sqrt{<w,w>-2r^2+<v,v>}$

From here can I just simply say $<u,u>$ and $<v,v>$ are both $r^2$ because they are both lines from the origin to the perimiter? This is what I have done and have ended up with:

$<w,w>=<w,w>$ where I conclude that $||w-u||=||w-v||.$

However I feel like this may not have been right to assume because if I do that surely I could just sub in $u=v=r$ right at the start which would defeat the object of any of this. Is there a better method to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Observe $ \Delta ABO and \Delta CBO $

$BO = BO$ (Common side)

Angle at $A$ and $C$ is equal to $90^0$

$AO = CO$ (Radius of circle)

Hence they are congruent. Hence $AB = BC$.

Now $ ||w-u|| = AB$ and $||w-v|| = BC$ and they are equal as proven above.

Comment: Have you used Angle Side Side (ASS) to say that these triangles are congruent? As it's possible for ASS triangles not to be congruent so would I be better off using say SAS with angles AOB and COB being equal? This would mean proving OB is the perpendicular bisector but not quite sure how to do that?